# Windows Update keeps offering same update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows 7 tells me I have an update to perform.  I have installed the update and it says it installed correctly.  Minutes later it says I have the same update to perform.  I installed same update 5 times.  Then I looked in "latest updates and find that there has not been a successful update for 10 days.  I ran a windows repair and it says," Service Registration is Missing or Corrupt."  Also says, "Win Update Error: 0x80070490(2018-04-17-T-05-00-52P).  The Repair could not fix either of these problems.  Does anyone know what they are or how to fix them??

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below:

**1. Repair damaged system files**

- Open search and type cmd.
- Right-click on the Command Prompt option and select Run as Administrator.
- Type sfc /scannow command in the run dialogue box and press Enter.
- Let the system perform the repair automatically. If possible, restart your PC after that and try to run Windows Update now.

**2. Use Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool**

- Open search and type cmd.
- Right-click on the Command Prompt option and select Run as Administrator.
- Type `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` command in the run dialogue box and press Enter.
  In case your Windows Update client is damaged, run the following command instead: `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess.`

*Reference: [How to Fix Windows Update Error Code 0x80070490?](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-windows-update-error-code-0x80070490/)*